# What does 休まないでください mean in the given contex?

Tags: meaning

I'm going through listening comprehension examples, and though, I can recognise separate words (well, most of them), particles, grammar and so on and recall their meaning, I still have trouble with understanding the whole sentences. In the example below, the phrase `休まないでください。` means don't rest, as far as understand, but the part that goes after contradicts it, by saying that students should 'take' a good rest for the next 6 days. Am I missing something? Or is something like "have a good rest, but don't relax too much since in 6 days you will back in school"?

> 皆さん、明日から休みですね。休みは四日から九日まで六日間です。十日はテストをします。**休まないでください。** では、六日間ゆっくり休んで、また学校に来てください。

Comment: Sounds like he's cautioning the students not to miss the day of the test.  Rest up the other six days, but don't take off on the day of the test.

Comment: What's your understanding of 休みは四日から九日まで六日間です。 and 十日はテストをします。 ? The latter seems like it's specific context for the request not to 休む, seeing as how it leaves out any reference to doing so (unlike the sentence before it).

Comment: Please check the meanings of the verb 休む in your dictionary. Does it not give "to be absent", as well as "to rest", like this: https://jisho.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keyword=%E3%82%84%E3%81%99%E3%82%80

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be three elements to your quoted text.

- There will a few days to take off.
- There will be an exam after the break.
- A summary statement.

The first of these is

> 明日から休みですね。休みは四日から九日まで六日間です。

The idea expressed is that starting *tomorrow* there will be six days of a break.

The second is

> 十日はテストをします。休まないでください。

After the break, on the 10th, there will be an exam.  The speaker urges the students "not take the day off".  For example, he may feel it could be easily after several days of a break to lose track and miss the exam accidentally.  Who knows.

And the third part is

> では、六日間ゆっくり休んで、また学校に来てください。

では here signals a summary:  Take a nice easy break fro six days, then please return to school.